# How to do my approach of connection management tcp in android works?

Tags: java, android, tcpclient

I'm writing here because i wanna some advices. I'm newbie in android and java. I explain my problem, I want to do a tcp client for android. My approach is as follows:

I have two class. The main_activity.class and the connection.class. In the main activity I have two edit text (One for write the ip and the other for write the message) and three buttons(connect, disconnect, send). The code is this:

```
private ConnectionManagement connection = Connection.getInstance();
public void click (View v){

        switch (v.getId()){
           case R.id.send:
                    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.message);
                    String message = editText.getText().toString();
                    connection.sendMessage(message);
                break;
            case R.id.connect:
                    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ip);
                    String ip = editText.getText().toString();
                    connection.setIp(ip);
                    new Thread(connection).start();
                break;
            case R.id.disconnect:
                connection.disconnect();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

And the connection.class code is this:

```
public class ConnectionManagement implements Runnable  {
    private static ConnectionManagement instance =  new ConnectionManagement();
    private String ip;
    private int port;
    private Socket connection;
    private PrintWriter printWriter;

    private ConnectionManagement(){
        this.ip = "127.0.0.1";
        this.port = 700;
    }

    public static ConnectionManagement getInstance(){
        return instance;
    }

    public void setIp(String ip){
        this.ip=ip;
    }

    public void setPort(int port){
        this.port=port;
    }

    public void run(){
            try {
                connection = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(this.ip), this.port);
                PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(connection.getOutputStream(), true);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }
    public void sendMessage(String message){
        printWriter.write(message);
    }

    public void disconnect(){
        try {

            printWriter.flush();
            printWriter.close();
            connection.close();

        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

In this moment this codes doesn't work. But my idea is do that the class connectionManagement have methods to start the connection and send some messages. If it's possible I want this class also have the thread control.
It's possible to do effectively my idea with my approach? Can you give me some advices? Did you could recommend me some literature that was useful for do this?

Thanks for your attention

Comment: The `sendMessage(...)` method will throw a `NullPointerException` because in the `run(...)` method you are declaring a new `printWriter` instead of initializing the `printWriter` class variable. Also you should take a look at [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: silly mistake xD thanks. But my question is.. this approach it's the best solution or is is better to use AsyncTask

Comment: If you use this code as it is, your GUI will freeze while you send messages. You should never execute blocking or long running operations on the main thread that is why I've suggested `AsyncTask` but since you application doesn't seem to update the GUI after you send a message you can simply create a new `Thread` in the `sendMessage(..,)`  function.